# MySQL Insert query doesn't work on Lamp

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I am using an MySQL db that contains 20 fields . In my CRUD form i am using only 10 of them the rest must be unchanged as informed from CSV file .

When in Windows environment and using Ampps all work as it should but when on Ubuntu lamp stack i must describe all database fields to run the crud operation

for example in a table i have 4 fields named custId,trndate,trnvisitors,scans

The next query works on Ampps but not on Lamp(Ubuntu) environment

```
$ins_query2="insert into trntime (`custId`,`trndate`,`trnvisitors`) values ('$custId','$trn_date','$visitors')"; 
$retval2 = mysqli_query( $con ,  $ins_query2);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Enable PHP error-reporting, and check if `$con->error;` returned anything. If it failed, it failed for a reason - and PHP/MySQL will gladly tell you what it is, if you just let it ;-)

Comment: it doesnt return anything and the message is success from json

Comment: Have you checked the table definitions are exactly the same, especially if fields are nullable or not.

Comment: the table is an export from ampps , But i think something has to do with null fields which although in ampps sql insert they are left blank (not null) in LAMP i have to put some of them NULL for sql insert to work